# Can I send and excelsheet with office script to someone in another organization

Tags: excel, office365, office-scripts

A client want me to create an excelfile for him which includes office script.

How can I do that without being part of the client's organization?
(scripts can't be shared with external accounts and I don't want to host excelfile and script anyway)

Is is possible to create some kind of package (Excelfile + script) the client can "install" in his organization's office365?

Will it work if the client just put the script file in his "Office-Script" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just send the person the script in an email, you can find the script in your personal OneDrive in this following location ...

[image]

... they just need to then copy it to their personal OneDrive and it will appear in Excel.

Comment: Thank your for the quick reply. Will it work also if I have "linked" the script to the excelsheet with a button?

Comment: Linked scripts to an excelsheet with a button will not work with a different organization. Currently only inter-organizational sharing is supported. You will need to send them the script which they can either upload directly to their OneDrive or that they can copy and paste into the Office Scripts editor.

Comment: Tested and it is too complicated for the client to handle. Will probably just lead to support questions in the future so I dropped the idea of using office script. Marks this as answer anyway.